# is it posible to create Response by "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" Content-Type header?

Tags: php, http-headers, httpresponse

i know that when a simple form post from client to server by `post` method, the sending request has this header:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

now, when the server return an answer to the request, is it posible to create the above header as Response header?

(My server language is PHP)

Comment: Have you looked into the [```header```](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function? BTW, are you sure you want to set the content type to that, though? Your server tipically returns HTML, JSON, XML, etc. never saw a x-www-form-urlencoded response...

Comment: thanks @mTorres. yes i want this for [telegram bot](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#making-requests-when-getting-updates).

Comment: I haven't look at the telegram bot in depth, but when you consume an API, you're acting as a client and not sending responses, but request (your PHP  code acts as the client because is asking resources to the server using the API provided). If that's your case, the ```header``` function won't work (it's to send back HTTP headers from a server point of view). Take a look at [guzzle](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) an HTTP client library written in PHP, you'll find very easy to make an HTTP request with whatever header you may need.

Comment: when i set a URL for web hook in telegram, any new meesage that user send to the robot, will be post to the URL (that i set). in this case, my server response to the webhook can be perform for sending new message as you see in the above link.